# Real analysis uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology

Is every differentiable function $f$ from the open interval $(0,1)$ to the closed interval $[0,1]$ uniformly continuous? No means please give counter example.

Answer (score 2):

No. Try to think of such an $f$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to0+}f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider  $f(x)={1\over 2}+{1\over 2}\sin {1\over x}$

Comment: There is no hypothesis implying that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: $1/x$ is not an example.  What is its range?

Comment: Yes, $\sin\frac1x$ is on the right track for a counterexample along the lines I suggested.  Of course, the range still isn't right, but this can easily be fixed.

Comment: should I multiply by $x$?

Comment: Senore: No, for 2 reasons: (1) That would make it uniformly continuous; (2) that wouldn't help the problem with the range.

Comment: or just add $1$?

Comment: Senore: No, that doesn't fix the problem with the range.  Think about what the range of $\sin(1/x)$ is.

Comment: range is $[-1,1]$

Comment: Senore: So if you add 1, you don't quite get $[0,1]$.

Comment: I will get $[0,2]$ so will it be ${1\over 2}+{1\over 2}\sin {1\over x}$?

Comment: Senore: Yes, that's a good example.  ($\sin^2\frac1x$ is another.) Are you comfortable with proving it is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: I know one result which says in a bounded open interval a continuous function is uniformly continuous iff limit exists finitely at the end points, here $\lim_{ x\downarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist finitely

Comment: Senore: That would do it.  In this case we can explicitly choose $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily close such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=1$ to prove directly it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you :)

Comment: sin(1/x) is a differentiable function?

Comment: @KaruppiahKannappan: Yes.  If your concern is that there is a singularity at $x=0$, recall that the domain is $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer. Thank you very much for your kind reply

Comment: I have one more doubt. Is the function $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ differentiable on the remaining points of (0,1)?

Comment: @KaruppiahKannappan: What does "remaining points of $(0,1)$" mean?  If you mean the boundary points $0$ and $1$, then note that the formula $\sin(1/x)$ may define a differentiable function on all of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, so in particular there is no problem at $x=1$.  However, there is no way to define the function at $x=0$ to even make it continuous, let alone differentiable.  If $f:\mathbb R\setminus\{a\}\to\mathbb R$ is a function, then $f(a)$ may be defined in such a way that the extended function is continuous at $x=a$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: But $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ does not exist.  Furthermore, any function that is continuous on $(0,1)$ and *does* have a continuous extension to $[0,1]$ must be uniformly continuous, and hence could not be a counterexample for your problem.  The reason is that the extension would be a continuous function on a compact interval, hence uniformly continuous (this is a theorem), and this automatically implies it is uniformly continuous on every subset of its domain including $(0,1)$. @KaruppiahKannappan